# Nullish coalescing javascript operator not working in edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

When I use the ?? javascript operator in Edge, I'm getting a syntax error. For instance, typing the following in the console in Chrome and Firefox works, but it gives a syntax error in Edge.

```
false ?? 1
```

Expected result: false

```
null ?? 1
```

Expected result: 1

As I said, this works Chrome and Firefox but results in a syntax error in Edge. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? MDN says Edge supports ??.

Comment: Tried it in Edge and is working fine. Version 81.0.416.68 (Official build) (64-bit)

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_nullish_coalescing

Comment: Hm, I must have an old version of Edge: Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edge Legacy doesn't support Nullish coalescing operator. You could check the [MDN Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator#Browser_compatibility) and [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_nullish_coalescing). It's only supported by Microsoft Edge version 80+.

If you want to use Nullish coalescing operator in Edge Legacy, you could use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile it.

Reference plugin: [@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator)